# Using a touchscreen monitor to sign within a website issue

Tags: touchscreen

I have web service that I use and within it they have a signature feature.  I can sign in the box with my mouse with the button clicked and with my surface pen with the button clicked.  I also have a drawing pad and if I set a setting within the driver software I can use it to sign without pressing a button on the pen.

However, when I try to use a touchscreen monitor with my finger or a regular stylus it doesn't mark within the signature box.  If i tap with my finger it makes a small mark but doesn't recognize that I am holding my finger down and keep drawing the signature.

Does anyone know of a setting either in the monitor driver, browser or other that I can change to make it work.  The company providing the web service refuses to help.

Kevin

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is interested, here is the fix:

Open a chrome browser window and type chrome://flags
Scroll down until you find Touch Events API
Changed it from it's current setting to Enabled
It should prompt you to restart chrome, if not, please close all chrome browser tabs and reopen them
You should be able to now sign signature fields in chrome using a touchscreen

Cheers, 
Kevin